# Single quotes prevent bindValue from replacing placeholder mark

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt5, qtsql

When I prepare a statement with bindValue the placeholder mark is not replaced if it is surrounded with single quotes. This is problematic since in SQL strings are surrounded by single quotes to avoid keyword conflicts.
See my attachements with screenies of the content of the database once inserted with and once without single quotes.
I already reported a [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45915), but meanwhile I am not sure anymore if this is not just an encoding problem. Is it correct to use single quotes, i.e. should this work/ is this really a bug?

With quoutes
[image]
Without quoutes
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a bug. Just don't use the single quotes. The bindValue mechanism does not just replace your :path with a string in your statement. No risk of name conflicts. See it as some kind of different namespace. :-)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement: Prepared statements are normally executed through a non-SQL binary protocol, for efficiency and protection from SQL injection, but with some DBMSs such as MySQL are also available using a SQL syntax for debugging purposes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Parameterized_statements: With most development platforms, parameterized statements that work with parameters can be used (sometimes called placeholders or bind variables) instead of embedding user input in the statement. **A placeholder can only store a value of the given type and not an arbitrary SQL fragment.** Hence the SQL injection would simply be treated as a strange (and probably invalid) parameter value.

Comment: Really I would like to just belive you, but could you please give me a sophisticated reference?

Comment: Difficult request. Can an indirect 'proof' satisfy you? See here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-bindvariables/ or http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters. Bound variable are among other things a protection against sql injections. This is because, the don't just replace their place holders. Bound variables are never 'executed' and for that reason never come in conflict with SQL keywords. I don't know if I can find better references than those above.

Comment: Well Im new to database coding. I didnt even know that there's that "huge" mechanism behind bindValue. With the reference I thought of the qt docs, but since this is generally sql related I am totally satisfied. Thank you, sir.